# I'm trying automate lifetables in python

Tags: python

```
Qx = [0.07230,0.02765,0.00851,0.00636,0.00641,0.00899,0.00814,0.00984,0.01497,0.02184,0.03175,0.04509,0.06498]
dx = []
lx = []
index = 0
deaths = 0


for i in Qx:
    starting_cohort = 100000 - deaths
    deaths = i * starting_cohort
    starting_cohort = starting_cohort - deaths
    lx.append(starting_cohort)
    dx.append(deaths)
    index += 1


print(dx)
print(lx)
```

I want to print lx which is the remaining population after subtracting deaths from starting cohort for each item in Qx. The problem is starting_cohort won't reset to a new value but instead stays as 100000.

Comment: What would be the expected output?

Comment: lx = [92770.0, 90204.9, 89437.3, 88868.4, 88298.8, 87505.0, 86792.7, 85938.7, 84652.2, 82803.4, 80174.3, 76559.3, 71584.5]

Comment: dx = [7230.0, 2565.1, 767.6, 568.8, 569.6, 793.8, 712.3, 854.0, 1286.5, 1848.8, 2629.0, 3615.1, 4974.8]

Comment: Well, you do `starting_cohort = 100000 - deaths` in every loop. Did you mean to do `starting_cohort = starting_cohort - deaths`?

Answer (score 1):

You must initiliaze `starting_cohort` outside the loop. If you initialize it inside the loop, the variable will keep basing its  value on 100000:

```py
# Initialize it outside the loop
starting_cohort = 100000

for i in Qx:
    deaths = i * starting_cohort
    starting_cohort = starting_cohort - deaths
    lx.append(starting_cohort)
    dx.append(deaths)
    index += 1
```

At the end of execution, this will assign

```
[7230.0,
 2565.0905000000002,
 767.6437798449999,
 568.8210099801857,
 569.6467305922205,
 793.8061938364474,
 712.2906331359735,
 854.040179341684,
 1286.5017547698294,
 1848.8031573320106,
 2629.0065549420415,
 3615.061419235668,
 4974.8225398925415]
```

to `dx` and

```
[92770.0,
 90204.9095,
 89437.26572015499,
 88868.44471017481,
 88298.79797958258,
 87504.99178574614,
 86792.70115261017,
 85938.66097326849,
 84652.15921849867,
 82803.35606116666,
 80174.34950622462,
 76559.28808698895,
 71584.4655470964]
```

to `lx` as expected.

---

Some minor improvements:

```
starting_cohort = 100000

# Use `enumerate` to access the index of each iteration
for index, i in enumerate(Qx):
    deaths = i * starting_cohort

    # Use the minus assignment operator 
    starting_cohort -= deaths

    lx.append(starting_cohort)
    dx.append(deaths)
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out putting the whole code in function solves everything

```
def simple_automation():
    Qx = [0.07230,0.02765,0.00851,0.00636,0.00641,0.00899,0.00814,0.00984,0.01497,0.02184,0.03175,0.04509,0.06498]
    dx = []
    lx = []
    Lx = []
    n = 1
    deaths = 0
    starting_cohort = 100000 
    for i in Qx:
        deaths = i * starting_cohort
        starting_cohort = starting_cohort - deaths
        dx.append(round(deaths, 1))
        lx.append(round(starting_cohort, 1))
        
    print(dx)
    print(lx)
    
simple_automation()
```